# Adding password for gpu-monitoring-tools?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I was testing [gpu-monitoring-tools](https://nvidia.github.io/gpu-monitoring-tools/) for our cluster but wondered how to add password for it. Could someone give me guidance? 
If I install the gpu-monitoring-tools with helm like described in the link, it doesn't require any credentials to see the metrics and I wonder how to add the password.

Comment: Do you mean on the exporter itself or on the Grafana installation that comes with kube-prometheus?

Comment: I mean the later (he Grafana installation that comes with kube-prometheus). If I install the gpu-monitoring-tools with helm, it doesn't doesn't require any credentials to see the metrics and I wonder how to add the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about [Grafana permissions](https://grafana.com/docs/permissions/overview/) There are only 3 Roles (Admin, Editor, Viewer). Also many depends on `Organization Role`.

If you have installed everything correctly according to gpu-monitoring-tools you shoudl have pod with grafana name.

`$ kubectl get pods -n monitoring | grep grafana`

Next if you will enter the grafana pod (kube-prometheus-grafana-69647b646f-rftvw from monitoring ns)

`$ kubectl exec -ti -n monitoring kube-prometheus-grafana-69647b646f-rftvw -c grafana /bin/bash`

Check what Grafana configuration file contains.

`$ cat /etc/grafana/grafana.ini`

Under Security section, you can find entry:

```
[security]
# default admin user, created on startup
;admin_user = admin
# default admin password, can be changed before first start of grafana,  or in profile settings
;admin_password = admin
```

So default Administrator pass to grafana is admin/admin

If you will scroll bellow to `Anonymous Auth`
You will have entries like:

```
# specify organization name that should be used for unauthenticated users
;org_name = Main Org.

# specify role for unauthenticated users
;org_role = Viewer
```

> Its mean that person who is not authorized have `Viewer` role. That is
>   why you are able to see metrics without any authentication.  But this
>   is only first time when you enter Grafana. If you will logout you need
>   to provide credentials

If you want to change password, on bottom left corner you have your user icon.

```
User Profile > Preferences > Change password
```

Second option if you are Administrator, on the left side of UI.

```
Configuration > Server Admin
```

On the `Users` tab you can change anyones password.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The default `username` and `password` for grafana is, `admin`:`admin`.
While logging in using these you will get option to change `username` and `password`.